# uninitialized constant error when joining 3 tables in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 tables. pin, genre and genres_pins.

genres_pins joins the pin and genre tables together with a many to many. Here's my setup:

**Pin Model**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :type
    has_many :replies
    has_many :genres_pins
    has_many :genres, :through => :genres_pins

end
```

**Genre Model**

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :genres_pins
    has_many :pins, :through => :genres_pins

end
```

**GenresPins Model**

```
class GenresPins < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :pin
    belongs_to :genre

end
```

**View**

```
<% pin.genres_pins.each do |g| %>
    <%= g.title %>
<% end %>
```

**I get the following error:**

```
uninitialized constant Pin::GenresPin
```

Any idea what's going on here? I'm new to Rails, so may be missing something stupidly obvious.

Help appreciated.

Many thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class GenrePin < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :pin
   belongs_to :genre
end
```

The name of the class should be changed

Comment: I just did this and continue to get the same error. My table is named genres_pins and my model file is named genres_pins.rb. Do I need to change the file name itself too?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo file name should be changed as well. no need to change the database table name

Comment: I still get the same error when changing it to genre_pin.rb. Weird! So, from plural to singular names.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo `has_many :genres_pins` should be changed to `has_many :genre_pins`

Comment: I changed the has_many in my pin and genre models and now I get the error in my view: undefined method `genres_pins'. Even changing this tp genre_pins results in a table error in MySQL. So, would I have to rename my table too? I have read in numerous places that having a join table like this should use the plural from both joined tables.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo the table name should be genre_pins. ASFAIK, there is no need to be plural of both.

Comment: Damn! That worked! Renaming the table to genre_pins and in reference with the models too did the trick. Thank you! Any reason why this worked, when prior, everything was the same, only with plurals?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo rails convention is like that. i'm sorry i cannot explain in detail